# PHP mail is not sending from mydomain.com to the google apps email myname@mydomain.com

Tags: php, email, google-apps

When i am trying to send a mail from a contact form in my website using the
PHP mail function its not sending from mydomain.com to the google apps email   myname@mydomain.com.

Please suggest a solution for the issue.

Comment: php mail function doesnot work locally unless you have to setup mercurry for it. Are you sending mail from live server?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I am looking for this solution from very long. I read that php mail() function is disabled for google apps account.

Answer (score 1):

After a very long research, I found the answer to this problem.

For me, the problem is in my host settings.

You host treats those domain addresses as they were registered with itself not with Google Apps. So it routes the emails to hosts mail server.

To route it through Google Apps (Gmail), you need to change the email routing settings.

Find "MX Entry" settings in your cpanel and add a new MX Record with priority

> 0

and destination

> gmail.com

and add it. You should also change the existing MX Record priority to 1.

These settings will let your receive emails from `php mail()` to your Google Apps gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

To send email from PHP you must have an SMTP server installed and have PHP configured to use the server. If you are using shared hosting or have it set up, you should check that you are calling the mail function correctly by checking the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Here is an example of how it is used:

```
$to = "name@example.com";
$subject = "Test Message";
$message = "Hello!";
$headers = "From: me@example.org";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, actually my issue is i cannot send contact mail to my google apps mail account ie, st@mydomain.com. Rest of the email accounts i can sent the mail.

Comment: @Nobis: Have you verified that the DNS is set up correctly for your Google Apps domain? Otherwise it sounds like an issue on the receiving end - unless the `mail` function fails when you call it

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the /etc/hosts file and add your IP Address mydomain.com mydomain in the next line, this should work by routing emails to google's servers .I did the same for my site.

So my /etc/hosts file looks like this :

127.0.0.1 localhost 
**IP**  **mysite.com**  **mysite**(this is an alias and you can call it anything i suppose)